# About Google Fused Location Provider and older versions of Android

Tags: android

If I get it correctly , the Google `FusedLocationProviderApi` is only available with the `SDK` versions above `17`. Does this mean that for most phones with the older versions we still have to use the "old" ways of tracking the location with all the drawback?

Answer (score 3):

No. Fused provider is part of Google Play Services so you can use it on older versions as well: https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html